# Override tag value within directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Given the following template:

```
<p title>Hello World</p>
```

How would I replace Hello World by another string from a directive?

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[title]'
})
export class TitleDirective{
  constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    renderer.setText(el.nativeElement, 'Hello another world');
  }
}
```

I only could find examples changing styles, attributes or listening to change events which does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my on question:

You have to implement OnInit with your directive and pass in the given node since you have to wait for the properties being set(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) by angular2:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[title]'
})
export class TitleDirective implements OnInit{
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setText(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0], 'Hello another world');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text inside the `<p>` tags, you should create a local variable inside your controller and bind to that.

.ts

```
private title = 'Hello World';
```

.html

```
<p>{{ title }}</p>
```

Now you can change the `title` variable inside your controller's functions, e.g.:

```
changeTitle(title: string) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

and call `this.changeTitle('Hello another World');`

Comment: This would not help since I want to use the text as a key and fetch values with a service based on the key. With this solution every component developer has to do this on his own.

Comment: Why can't you pass the text as a parameter to the service method?

Comment: I could do it in the component as you suggested but you have to do it everytime in every component it its high repetitive code. The goal is to use the directive and don't worry about how the values are being replaced.